# Why I am not able to make private operator new and use default implementation?

Tags: c++

I have simple code

```
template <class T>
class SmartPointer //not completely implemented yet 
{
    T* ptr;

public:
    void CrateObj()
    {
        ptr = new T;
    }
};

class MyClass
{
private:
    static void * operator new   (size_t);
    static void* operator new[] (size_t);
    friend class SmartPointer<MyClass>;
};

int main()
{
    SmartPointer<MyClass> a;
    a.CrateObj();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static void *
>   __cdecl MyClass::operator new(unsigned int)" (??2MyClass@@CAPAXI@Z)

I want to make sure only SmartPointer should be able to create an instance using new. How can I do that?

Comment: You haven't **implemented them**. That's why you get a *linkage error*.

Comment: @StoryTeller I want to use default implementation.

Comment: So call the default implementation from your custom one. You can't declare a function, have it be picked in overload resolution, and expect the default global one to be resolved for it.

Comment: @StoryTeller You mean to say something like `void * operator new   (size_t) {return new MyClass}`?

Comment: `new MyClass` will just call your operator new recursively again. Your operator new should allocate raw memory. It should **not** create any objects.

Comment: The *much easier* way of ensuring only trusted things can construct `MyClass` is to make the *constructor* private. You can even give friendship to `std::make_unique<MyClass>` and avoid the entirety of `SmartPointer`

Comment: @Caleth Thanks. That was a great insight.

Comment: Mind you however, that it will allow creating *only* items on the free store. No automatic variables. There is no perfect solution to this.

Comment: @StoryTeller I do not get your point, can you please elaborate?

Comment: The point is simple. If you define a private c'tor, you can't write a simple `MyClass obj;` in any function.

Comment: @StoryTeller Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to overload it just for the access specifier, but still call the default global `operator new` you need to call it explicitly in your custom implementation. Overload resolution will not use your custom declaration to call the global function on its own. A function declared and called needs a definition:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    static void* operator new   (size_t sz) { return ::operator new(sz); }
    static void* operator new[] (size_t sz) { return ::operator new[](sz); }
    friend class SmartPointer<MyClass>;
};
```

Though you should be aware that it won't stop a determined user who knows the language. They too can defer to the global allocation function:

```
int main()
{
    SmartPointer<MyClass> a;
    a.CrateObj();

    auto* raw_ptr = ::new MyClass;
    return 0;
}
```